# Undefined Reference With Freetype And Mingw

Tags: linux, mingw, mingw32, freetype, freetype2

I've got a simple program:

```c
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cglm/cglm.h>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

int main(void){
    /* Initializing fonts  */
    FT_Library ft;
    if(FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed initializing Freetype\n");
        return -1;
    }
    /* * * * * * * * * * * */

    return 0;
}
```

Which I compile with:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc game.c -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 -lfreetype -lmingw32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lpthread -lm $(pkg-config --cflags freetype2 | sed "s//usr///usr/i686-w64-mingw32//g") -O3 -o Game
```

There seems to be an error at the time of linking the program:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYBzSJN.o:main.c:(.text.startup+0x13e): undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `sed "s//usr///usr/i686-w64-mingw32//g"` won't work. Maybe `sed "s?/usr/usr/i686-w64-mingw32??g" might work, but I recommend you use` pkg-config --define-prefix --cflags freetype2`without sed, to let`pkg-config` figure out the correct path.

Also, you are compiling and linking with one line, so you will also need to add the linker flags (`pkg-config --define-prefix --libs freetype2`).

So try something like this:

```sh
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc game.c -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 -lfreetype -lmingw32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lpthread -lm $(pkg-config --define-prefix --cflags --libs freetype2) -O3 -o Game
```